# requirejs & knockoutjs ko.computed Pass a function that returns the value of the ko.computed

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I have having an issues trying to get knockout to play nicely with requirejs (and judging by the number of posts on here, so is everyone else!).  Nothing I have read on here have come across this issue.

Below is my config for require:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "/js",
    "paths": {
        "Model": "App/Model",
        "Development": "App/Development",
        "Property": "App/Property",
        "codemirror": "vendor/codemirror/codemirror-2.37/lib/codemirror",
        "galleria": "vendor/galleria/galleria-1.2.9",
        "jquery": "vendor/jquery/jquery-2.0.0",
        "jquery-ui": "vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2",
        "jshint": "vendor/jshint/jshint-1.1.0",
        "knockout": "vendor/knockout/knockout-2.2.1",
        "signalr": "vendor/signalR/jquery.signalR-1.0.1"
    },
    "shim": {
        "galleria": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "jquery-ui": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "signalr": ["jquery"],
        "/signalr/hubs": {
            deps: ["jquery", "signalr"]
        },
        "Development/ViewModel/CreateDevelopment": {
            deps: ["signalr", "knockout"]
        },
        "knockout": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "knockout"
        }
    }
});
```

So this should get all of my dependencies, and indeed it does.  Here is the require bit:

```
require(["Development/ViewModel/CreateDevelopment"], function (CreateDevelopment) {

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        if (CreateDevelopment !== undefined && CreateDevelopment !== null) {
            var createDevelopment = new CreateDevelopment();
            createDevelopment.init();
        }
    });
})
```

I will probably need to bring in the singalr jquery bit but thats not where I am having an issue.

When I define my module I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Pass a function that returns the value of the ko.computed (Line 44)
```

Here is my module

```
define(["Model/developmentType", "knockout", "signalr", "/signalr/hubs"], function (developmentType, ko)
```

Now if I use console.log(ko) I can see everything in the library so I cannot understand why I keep getting this error.

The order in which require is getting the libraries is as follows:

- RequireJS
- Main AppJs
- Jquery
- Jquery SignalR
- Knockout
- ViewModel
- Model
- Hubs

  Uncaught Error: Pass a function that returns the value of the ko.computed

Call Stack:
[image: call stack]

Any help with this will be greatly received!

Comment: could you share line 44 of that file?

Comment: its the knockoutjs library - it's been minified :(

Comment: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/dependentObservable.js line 18

Comment: Can you get the callstack?  Need to see what ko.computed that is being defined.  Doesn't seem like a require.js issue specifically.

Comment: Updated question with the call stack

Comment: Errrr, it's official. I am stupid - ko.dependentObservable should be ko.observableArray() ... *Sigh*  Thanks for your help though

Comment: @Matt: You could add that as an answer and accept it so that it will help others reading this :)

Comment: Matt, as of Knockout 2.0 "dependentObservable()" is now called "computed()".  According to the docs, you can still use "dependentObservable" for backwards compatibility, but I find that using the name "computed" helps to keep me from making the exact same mistake you just made (becaue I may have done that once or twice).  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Floyd Pink I didn't want to highlight my stupidity!

Comment: @RyanRahlf Good to know I'm not the only one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Knockout 2.0, dependent observables are called computed observables. So:

```
self.typeList = ko.dependentObservable();
```

Should be replaced with:

```
self.typeList = ko.computed(function(){
   // Compute value here...
   return value;
});
```